# How do I create a new column in R with variable look up? R programming

Tags: r, variables, data.table, col

I have a data table that looks like:

```
    Cause of Death                Ethnicity                 Count
1: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING ASIAN & PACIFIC ISLANDER  1368
2: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING                 HISPANIC  3387
3: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING       NON-HISPANIC BLACK  3240
4: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING       NON-HISPANIC WHITE  6825
5:              ALZHEIMERS DISEASE ASIAN & PACIFIC ISLANDER   285
---
```

I'd like to create a new column that is simply the percent of people between ethnicities that pass away from a a specific cause of death. Like so:

```
   Cause of Death                Ethnicity                  Count  PercentofDeath
1: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING ASIAN & PACIFIC ISLANDER  1368     0.09230769
2: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING                 HISPANIC  3387     0.22854251
3: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING       NON-HISPANIC BLACK  3240     0.21862348
4: ACCIDENTS EXCEPT DRUG POISONING       NON-HISPANIC WHITE  6825     0.46052632
5:              ALZHEIMERS DISEASE ASIAN & PACIFIC ISLANDER   285     0.04049446
---
```

Here's my code to do it, which is quite ugly:

```
   library(data.table)
   #load library, change to data table
   COD.dt <- as.data.table(COD)


   #function for adding the percent column
   lala  <- function(x){ 

   #see if I have initialized data.table I'm going to append to


      if(exists("started")){
        p <- COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]
        blah <- COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]$Count/sum(COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]$Count)
        p$PercentofDeath <- blah
        started <<- rbind(started,p)
      }

       #initialize data table
        else{
            l <- COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]
            blah <- COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]$Count/sum(COD.dt[x ==`Cause of Death`]$Count)
            l$PercentofDeath <- (blah)
            started <<- l  
        }

 #if finished return
if(x == unique(COD.dt$`Cause of Death`)[length(unique(COD.dt$`Cause of Death`))]){
  return(started)
 }
 }

 #run function
 h <- sapply(unique(COD.dt$`Cause of Death`), lala)
  #remove from environment
 rm(started)
 #h is actually ends up being a list, the last object happen to be the one I want so I take that one
 finalTable <- h$`VIRAL HEPATITIS`
```

So, as you can see. This code is quite ugly, and not adaptable. I was hoping from some guidance as to how to make this better. Maybe using dpylr, or some other function?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure data-table solution will be easy as well, but here's dplyr:

```
 library(dplyr)

COD.dt %>% group_by(`Cause of Death`) %>%
    mutate(PercentofDeath = Count / sum(Count))
```

You *could* turn this into a function, but it's such a small, basic operation that most people wouldn't bother.

Comment: oooo. That's nice. I've been meaning to use the %>% operator more. Thanks so much.

Comment: Not sure if it improves readability, but with magrittr, `PercentofDeath  = Count %>% { ./sum(.) }` works inside the `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a way better way:

```
 library(data.table)
 #load library, change to data table
 COD.dt <- as.data.table(COD)

 #make column of disease total counts
 COD.dt[,disease:=sum(Count), by = list(`Cause of Death`)] 

 #use that column to make percents
 COD.dt[,percent:=Count/disease, by = list(`Cause of Death`)]
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be two separate steps. Unless you want the `disease` column for other reasons, you could just do `percent := Count / sum(Count)`.

Comment: Also, you can modify `COD` in place instead of making a separate object, like `setDT(COD)`.

Comment: Oh. Good to know. Sweet. Thanks! @Gregor